# Postgresql: ERROR: type "citext" does not exist

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have read other posts, when searching, an answer to this question.

I am using PostgreSQL 9.1, and created extension 'citext' using `CREATE EXTENSION citext`, but when I try to create any columns of type 'citext', it throws this error

> ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist

I researched but did not find any concrete answers? Any idea why?

Answer (score 167, accepted):

Ok figured it out. I have several databases and `CREATE EXTENSION citext` has to be run for each db to install the extension in that DB. You must do on psql prompt:

```
psql =# \c db_1
CREATE EXTENSION citext;

psql =# \c db_2
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
```

Comment: Is there any way of making this extension globally, so that every database can use it?

Comment: You can also automate this process as described in the docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#creating-extension-using-migrations. Remember that your postgres user needs to be superuser.

Comment: @MikeH-R [shaunc's answer can help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981197/postgresql-error-type-citext-does-not-exist#answer-45982923)

Comment: Thanks, it worked for me. For pgAdmin Users: Right-click on the Database name, open the Query Tool, and simply execute `CREATE EXTENSION citext;` Then you can create tables with citext columns in this database.

Answer (score 33):

@NullException is correct that the extension needs to be created in each database. If you want to automatically have an extension created, you can create it in the `template1` database which (by default, at least) is the database used as a model for "create database", so with appropriate permissions, in psql:

```
\c template1
create extension citext;
```

Then new databases will include citext by default.

Comment: This answer was helpful for me in running Django unittests which automatically creates a new test database for the tests and then drops it when done. That precludes the ability to connect to the database to create the extension.

Comment: *＋1* for keeping the site tidy.

Answer (score 20):

To use `citext`, use the `CITextExtension` operation to setup the `citext` extension in PostgreSQL before the first `CreateModel` migration operation.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#citext-fields

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CITextExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...

    operations = [
        CITextExtension(),
        ...
    ]
```

similarly to `HStoreField` as
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/postgres/operations/#create-postgresql-extensions

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this. I was 20 migrations deep when I implemented this. On migration 21, it works just as well as adding it into the first migration.

Answer (score 4):

If you use Docker, and want to add this extension to your database,

I have done the following,

```
# Dockerfile
FROM postgres:11.3

# Adds the CIText Extension to our database
COPY ./compose/production/postgres/initdb_citext.sh /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/citext.sh
```

And my initdb_citext.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

# Adds the citext extension to database and test database
"${psql[@]}" <<- 'EOSQL'
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;
\c template1
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;
EOSQL
```

This applies the extension to test databases that django generates too.