# Removing case sensitivity from Email in Django login form

Tags: python, django

I've created a custom UserModel and used Email as main authenticating id instead of username.

The problem that it is case sensitive, as it counts test@gmail.com,Test@gmail.com as 2 different accounts.

I need to force it to deal with both as 1 account ignoring if it upper or lower case.

Here are my files :

**models.py**

```
class UserModelManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, password, pseudo):
        user = self.model()
        user.name = name
        user.email = self.normalize_email(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()

        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, password):
        '''
        Used for: python manage.py createsuperuser
        '''
        user = self.model()
        user.name = 'admin-yeah'
        user.email = self.normalize_email(email=email)
        user.set_password(password)

        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()

        return user


class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    ## Personnal fields.
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=254, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=16)
    ## [...]

    ## Django manage fields.
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELD = ['email', 'name']

    objects = UserModelManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.name[:2].upper()

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.name
```

signup view in **views.py**

```
def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        signup_form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        if signup_form.is_valid():
            signup_form.save()
            username = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            raw_password = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            return redirect('signup_confirm')
    else:
        signup_form = SignUpForm()

    context = {
        'signup_form': signup_form,
    }
    return render(request, 'fostania_web_app/signup.html', context)


def signup_confirm(request):
    return render(request, 'fostania_web_app/signup_confirm.html')
```

the sign up form in **forms.py**:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.CharField(required=True, help_text='البريد الإلكترونى الخاص بك - يجب ان يكون حقيقى (يستخدم لتسجيل الدخول) ')
    name = forms.CharField(required=True, help_text='إسمك الحقيقى -  سيظهر كأسم البائع')
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text='كلمة المرور - حاول ان تكون سهلة التذكر بالنسبة لك')
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput,
                                help_text='تأكيد كلمة المرور - إكتب نفس كلمة المرور السابقة مرة أخرى')

    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('email','name',  'password1', 'password2', )
        labels = {
            'name': 'إسمك الحقيقى -  سيظهر كأسم البائع',
            'email': 'البربد الإلكترونى Email',
            'password1': 'كلمة المرور',
            'password2': 'تأكيد كلمة المرور'
        }
```

All that I need now is to make it simply ignores the case sensitivity.

**update**

here is my login files

**urls.py**

```
   path('login/', auth_views.login, name='login'),
```

**registartion/login.html**

```
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    البريد الإلكترونى E-Mail &nbsp;<Br>{{ form.username }}
                    <br><br>
                     كلمة المرور &nbsp;<Br>{{ form.password }}
                    <Br><br>
      <div align="center">
    <button class ="btn btn-primary" submit>تسجيل الدخول</button><br><br>
      <a href="{% url 'signup' %}"><button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
          إنشاء حساب جديد</button></a>
          </div>

  </form>
```

Comment: Read this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34095774

Comment: and [this warning](https://django-improved-user.readthedocs.io/en/stable/email_warning.html) from a package providing similar functionality.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Addendum 2023:

According to this [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.3.11), the local part of the address before the `@` is to be handled by the mail host at its own terms, it mentions nothing about a standard requiring the local part to be lowercase, neither to handle addresses in a case insensitive way, even if most mail servers will do so nowadays.

This means that a mail server actually can discard mails sent to `user.name@mail.tld` if the account is set up as `User.Name@mail.tld`. This is also reflected in the original [normalize_email](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/4.1.x/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L20) method of Django's `BaseUser` class, it only forces the domain part to be lowercase for this reason. Considering this, we have to store the local part of the address in is original format.

That being said, we can still enforce a case insensitive uniqueness check before saving the user to the DB. If we make an educated guess, we can assume that even if a mail server was set up to handle addresses case sensitive for historical reasons, that it has started to validate their uniqueness in a case insensitive way to avoid impersonation.

### Django 4.0 and beyond

Django 4.0 comes with [Functional unique constraints](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/constraints/#expressions) which is probably the most portable and specific solution:

```py
from django.db.models import UniqueConstraint
from django.db.models.functions import Lower

class User:
    # ...
    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(
                Lower("email"),
                name="user_email_ci_uniqueness",
            ),
        ]
```

### Django before 4.0

This is not tested and syntax is from memory (also probably you have to display the validation error manually instead on the field because it will be hidden in the form) but it should convey the potential workaround.

```
from django.db import models

class User:
    # ...
    email = models.EmailField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
    )
    email_lower = models.EmailField(
        blank=False,
        null=False,
        unique=True,
        editable=False,
        error_messages={
            "unique": "A user is already registered with this email address",
        },
    )

    def clean(self):
        super().clean()
        self.email_lower = self.email.lower()
```

## Original Post:

You don't need to change much to accomplish this - in your case you just need to change the form and make use of Django's built-in [form data cleaners](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-a-specific-field-attribute) or by making a [custom field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-model-fields/).

You should use the `EmailField` instead of a `CharField` for built-in validation. Also you did not post your AuthenticationForm, but i presume you have changed it to include `email` instead of `username`.

With data cleaners:

```
class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    # your code
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        return data.lower()

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    # your code
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    def clean_email(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['email']
        return data.lower()
```

With a custom field:

```
class EmailLowerField(forms.EmailField):
    def to_python(self, value):
        return value.lower()

class SignUpForm(UserCreationForm):
    # your code
    email = EmailLowerField(required=True)

class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    # your code
    email = EmailLowerField(required=True)
```

This way you can make sure that each email is saved to your database in lowercase and that for each login attempt the email is lowercased before compared to a database value.

Answer (score 21):

A cleaner approach might be to override the model field itself if you don't mind losing the formatting of how the user entered their email.

This worked better for me because I only had to change it in one place. Otherwise, you might have to worry about Signup, Login, User Update, API views, etc.

The only method you will have to overwrite is [`to_python`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1555e5850df0a442154e2ce5e54d47bbb013ff66/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1064-L1067). This will just lowercase anything being saved to the `UserModel.email` field.

```py
from django.db import models


class LowercaseEmailField(models.EmailField):
    """
    Override EmailField to convert emails to lowercase before saving.
    """
    def to_python(self, value):
        """
        Convert email to lowercase.
        """
        value = super(LowercaseEmailField, self).to_python(value)
        # Value can be None so check that it's a string before lowercasing.
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value.lower()
        return value
```

Your user model would then just be..

```py
# Assuming you saved the above in the same directory in a file called model_fields.py
from .model_fields import LowercaseEmailField

class UserModel(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = LowercaseEmailField(unique=True)
    # other stuff...
```

Answer (score 2):

When creating the account entry, interpret the email as `email.lower()` to create a normalised entry in your database.

When parsing the email/username from a log in form, you should also use `email.lower()` to match the database entry.

---

**Note:** the [`normalize_email`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.models.BaseUserManager.normalize_email) only sanitises the domain portion of an email address:

> `classmethod normalize_email(email)`
>
> Normalizes email addresses by lowercasing the domain portion of the email address.

Comment: There's a [reason](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/5605) django only lowercases the domain part. From [RFC5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-2.4): "The
   local-part of a mailbox MUST BE treated as case sensitive.
   ...  In particular, for some hosts, the user "smith" is different from the user "Smith"."

Answer (score 2):

For anyone using **Postgres** and django 2 or higher:

There is a [`CIEmailField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.CIEmailField) that stores and retrieves the email address case sensitive but *compares* it case insensitive. This has the benefit of preserving case in the address (should a user want their address to look like `JohnDoe@ImportantCompany.com`) without allowing multiple accounts with the same email.

Usage is simple:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.fields import CIEmailField
# ...
class User(AbstractBaseUser, ...):
    email = CIEmailField(unique=True, ...)
    # ...
```

Except on migrating I got the error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: type "citext" does not exist
```

To solve this, follow [this so answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57892467/8811010) and set up the `CITextExtension` before the first `CreateModel` migration operation:

```
from django.contrib.postgres.operations import CITextExtension

class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    ...

    operations = [
        CITextExtension(),
        ...
    ]
```

*Note: both in the so answer and in the [official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#citext-fields) is stated that you should add it before the first CreateModel migration operation. For me it was sufficient to add it in the first migration that uses the `CIEmailField`.*

Comment: Note: as of Django 4.2 the `CIEmailField` field is deprecated in favour of just using `EmailField(db_collation="…")`. See the docs for more info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#django.contrib.postgres.fields.CIEmailField

Comment: Additional comment: there's a great writeup on how to switch from `CIEmailField` here. They also state that this is supported as of Django 3.2, so can be done for any django version since then: https://adamj.eu/tech/2023/02/23/migrate-django-postgresql-ci-fields-case-insensitive-collation/

Answer (score 0):

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, name, tc, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email).lower(),
            name = name,
            tc = tc
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice I do is write middleware and small all the URLs in urls.py

```
class LowercaseMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        request.path_info = request.path_info.lower()
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

and don't forget to add it in middlewares in settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    ...,
    'settings.middlewares.LowercaseMiddleware',
]
```

and also make all the URLs in url.py in lower case.