# Django CustomUserModel email field case sensitive

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-forms, django-authentication

Email field in the Django(3.0) Custom User Model is case sensitive, I tried various ways to make it case-insensitive but no success so far.

#### Code

forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','email','password1','password2')


class UserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','email',)

class UserUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    '''
    model form are the form that work with specific user model
    '''
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name','last_name','username','email',)



class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    '''
    model form are the form that work with specific user model
    '''
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']
```

manager.py

```
class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Must have Email')
        if not username:
            raise ValueError('Must have username')
        if not first_name:
            raise ValueError('Must have first_name')
        if not last_name:
            raise ValueError('Must have last name')

        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, username, first_name, last_name, password=None):

        user = self.create_user(
            email=email,
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            password=password,
        )
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
```

#### Model.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):

    #   compulsory fields
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(
        unique=True,  max_length=255,  null=True, blank=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(
        unique=False, max_length=255,  null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(
        unique=False, max_length=255,  null=True, blank=False, verbose_name='Last Name')

    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'username']

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self. username}'

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_admin


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
```

there are two models that interact with User, one is `User` and other is `Profile`. (`Profle` handles images)

#### Things already tried

- One of the very obvious things to try is **to make email lowercase** in manager.py before any authentication and so I did like this

manage.py (modified)

```
       user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email( **email.lower()** ), # <- notice change here
                username=username,
                first_name=first_name,
                last_name=last_name,
            )

        user = self.create_user(
            email=email.lower() ,  # <-- notice change here
            username=username,
            first_name=first_name,
            last_name=last_name,
            password=password,
        )
```

but this didn't work.

- Second was this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895643/removing-case-sensitivity-from-email-in-django-login-form), this is another StackOverflow post which I followed which didn't work either

I am trying to solve this problem for hours and can't think of anything else, would really appreciate some advice.

Comment: can you add your model here ?

Comment: @AstikAnand sure, wait.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Removing case sensitivity from Email in Django login form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50895643/removing-case-sensitivity-from-email-in-django-login-form)

Comment: @bones225 No it didn't and I did mention that In question.

Comment: Unfortunately, email addresses are supposed to be treated as (possibly) case sensitive. See e.g. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5321#section-2.4 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/9807909