# Postgres database : type "citext" does not exist

Tags: postgresql

I have been trying to create a table column of type "citext" in postgres.

```
db=# CREATE TABLE users (
  id serial PRIMARY KEY,
  name citext NOT NULL,
  email citext NOT NULL
);

ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist
LINE 3:   name citext NOT NULL,
```

But getting this error. On surfing through internet, it was said to

```
CREATE EXTENSION citext;
```

I verified the creation using command,

```
SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'citext';
```

It was created.

But even after this I keep on getting the error,

```
ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist
```

Does anyone knows how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgresql: ERROR: type "citext" does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15981197/postgresql-error-type-citext-does-not-exist)

Comment: On surfing through internet, it was said to

CREATE EXTENSION citext; 
I verified the creation using command,

SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'citext';
It was created.

But even after this I keep on getting the error,

ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist

Comment: as you see in my link, for  **every** database you need to run the command, that is a postgres thing

Comment: Best bet is the extension is not in your [search_path](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH). In `psql` run `show search_path;` and add the result to your question. Also do `SELECT extnamespace::regnamespace FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'citext';` and add the result to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you need to run to resolve the issue:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;
```

This will ensure that the `citext` extension is created if it doesn't exist. After running this command, you should be able to create a table column with the `citext` data type without encountering the "type does not exist" error.

Comment: I did. 
I verified the creation using command,


`SELECT * FROM pg_extension WHERE extname = 'citext';`

It was created.


But even after this I keep on getting the error,

`ERROR:  type "citext" does not exist`

How to resolve this?

Comment: What schema was `citext` installed, and do you have access to the schema?

Comment: I have `set search_path to a schema` and then executed this.

`CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS citext;`

Yes, I have access to the schema.